# Disable change of a spritenode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game where i'm creating an `SKSpriteNode` at the bottom. Cause i want to make a buttom higher than the actually bottom cause of grass as the background. The problem is after I've created the physics body and my moving `SKSpriteNode` makes contact with the bottom. the bottom SpriteNode that i've created will move.

How can i make the bottom sprite node which has the function as being the bottom edge, not move at all. By that i mean that it cant change position.

My code:

```
SKSpriteNode *bottom = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*2, 98)];
    bottom.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
bottom.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self addChild:bottom];

bottom.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bottom.size];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `dynamic` property of the physics body to `NO`. You are doing it before you actually create a physics body. That's why it does not have any effect. Change your code to:

```
SKSpriteNode *bottom = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor clearColor]
                                                    size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*2, 98)];

bottom.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bottom.size];  
bottom.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
bottom.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

[self addChild:bottom];
```

And it should work.